# What was the brand of whisky that Rossi received?

Tags: criminal-minds

I was just watching the newest episode of Criminal Minds (12x09 Profiling 202) and in that episode agent David Rossi receives a bottle of whisky as a birthday present.

I am a whisky aficionado myself and wanted to know what was the brand of whisky that Rossi got.

Here's a screencap of it:
[image]

I tried Google Image search "single malt scotch whisky" and identifying it from a picture but came up with nothing.
I am not American, maybe it is some sort of a brand popular in the US or found only in the US?

It also might be possible that it's a fake and they just designed a new "brand" and package for the show purposes.

If anyone can help me find it (or definitely tell me it was just made for the show) I'd be grateful

Comment: I think you can be sure it's a generic prop. Especially since there is no branding or distillery name of any kind on the front of the box.

Comment: Is it just me, or does it look like they taped a white piece of paper over the top of the box there?